# Spring Data Rest : What should be the return type of Query

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, return-type

I want to execute the follwoing query but when I used the `object[]` as return type it gives the error of "PersistentEntity must not be null!" What should be the return type of this query ?

```
public interface PropertyRepository  extends JpaRepository<Property, Long>,JpaSpecificationExecutor {

     @Query(value="select p.city.name, count(p) from Property p join p.city group by p.city.id")
     Object[] countPropertyInCities();
    }
```

Comment: propery om? @hovanessyan

Answer (score 1):

Your query will return a `List<Object[]>`.

Try this

```
@Query(value="select p.city.name as name, count(p) as pCount from Property p join p.city c group by c.id")
List<Object[]> countPropertyInCities();
```

I suggest you try JPA [`Projections`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) to only fetch entity properties that your actually need.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PersistentEntity must not be null! 
Still same error

Comment: Please check your query!